How to turn the search bar into an icon at the top of the wordpress website?
I've been trying for a few weeks to figure out how to turn the search bar (in this case, a plugin) into an icon at the top of the site, close to the header.
I've already tried editing the child theme's fuctions.php, the parent theme's header.php, the css, everything you can imagine and it doesn't work.
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]]' ); ?>
/**
 * After setup theme hook

 */
function blossom_chic_theme_setup(){
    /*
     * Make chile theme available for translation.
     * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
     */
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'blossom-chic', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );

}

The objective is what I tried to show in the picture:


I will be able to assit you much easily if you tell me about the theme you are using and the page builder you have as a plugin.
How to have an icon in header ?
This depends upon the page builder that you are using .
Try with Elementor Page builder , if you have the option and your theme should support this page builder .Themes like ASTRA and The Elementor theme.
Else
more information is needed .

The theme I'm using is glossom-chic, an ascendant theme of glossom-feminine. The plugin I'm using is ajax search.
This site already exists, but it was completely out of date and I had to update it locally, from plugins to php and wordpress.
There was a standard search for the theme itself, but it stopped working due to the update. There was also a search icon at the top like the figure shown.
However, I had to look for a plugin or a search that worked properly and insert this icon, but I'm not having any success. I've been testing for over a week now.
